# What is the legal term for someone who isn't a romantic partner but lives in the same house as you?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

A cohabitator but not a girlfriend or boyfriend or common-law spouse.

Comment: Roommate, flatmate, roomy.

Comment: Housemate should suit.

Comment: Did you put "law" intentionally before the question? Are you expecting a legal term which doesn't seem to exist unless they enter into a tenancy agreement? Co-tenant?

Answer (score 3):

If you co-own the property together, a UK term is "Tenant in common" - this is usually a couple arrangement, but not necessarily

If one of you owns the property, you are Live-in-Landlord and Tenant, but typically referred to as Roommates/Housemates, or Tenant-Roommate/Housemate, Landlord-Roommate/Housemate

If you rent together, housemates, co-tenants, or joint tenants would both be acceptable terms. The former being more common, the latter more formal.

Co-tenants/joint tenants are phrases independent of being in a couple: they aren't exclusive or being a couple, nor do you have to be in a couple

Comment: "housemate" is is current usage in AmE. +1

Comment: In the US, there are three ways for two or more people to co-own property.  Tenancy in common is one.  The other two are joint tenancy and tenancy of the entirety.  All three are legal terms of art and affect the ownership differently in certain circumstances.  I wouldn't use any of them in informal usage.

Answer (score -1):

The US Census Bureau refers to a [POSSLQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSSLQ), or "a person of opposite sex sharing living quarters."

Comment: That article suggests that this term is generally used to imply a sexual/romantic relationship. Also, there is nothing in the original question that restricts it to people of opposite sexes.